# StaggeredGridLayoutManager with CardView doesnt fit item measure

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I'm trying to use the *StaggeredGridLayoutManager* with *CardView* from `android.support.v7.widget` (v22).
This is my item's layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"      >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

On emulators and on devices 5.0+ it is ok and works well, but on emulators 4.x.x the image is not resized to fill the item's width / height (as there was like a scale type *centerInside* that not fit the item's measure ).
I cant now try it on real 4.x.x devices, does anyone know if it is a problem only in the emulator or even in some real 4.x.x devices?

**SOLVED**
from docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)][1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean))

> If the application targets API level 17 or lower, adjustViewBounds
>   will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to
>   fill available measured space in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related only to the behavior of `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, which seems that from Android 4.3 to be able to scale the image in ImageView not only to resize the native dimensions downward but also **upward** keeping the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Although very late but i am sure this should be the approved answer. We would have to create our own ImageView and measure the alternate dimensions based on the available fixed height/width. @Nuuneoi has done his best to bring it into action. Please follow this Github [link](https://github.com/nuuneoi/AdjustableImageView)

Comment: Results on API level 15 and 21 have no difference at all, after using AdjustableImageView